# Why can't asynchronous threads modify an ArrayList simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I am studying threads and came across this snippet here:

We create and start two identical `java.lang.Thread`s and have them modify an `ArrayList` continuously without doing anything about this being non-thread-safe because we're just making a research.

Both threads are just instances of the same class `NoteThread`. In the `run()` method there are two operations:

1. `add(item)` to the list
2. `remove(0)` from the list.

These two operations execute in 1000 iterations.

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new NoteThread().start();
        new NoteThread().start();
    }

    public static class Note {

        public static final List<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();

        public static void addNote(String note) {
            notes.add(0, note);
        }

        public static void removeNote(String threadName) {
            String note = notes.remove(0);
            if (note == null) {
                System.out.println("Another thread has already deleted the note");
            } else if (!note.startsWith(threadName)) {
                System.out.println("Thread [" + threadName + "] has deleted [" + note + "]");
            }
        }
    }

    public static class NoteThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                Note.addNote(getName() + "-Note" + i);
                Note.removeNote(getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes, it can throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: -1` when the list is empty and I fail to understand how that can be possible.

An example of output:

```
Thread [Thread-1] has deleted [Thread-0-Note597]         
Another thread has already deleted the note         
Thread [Thread-0] has deleted [Thread-1-Note558]         
Another thread has already deleted the note         
Thread [Thread-1] has deleted [Thread-0-Note635]         
Another thread has already deleted the note         
Thread [Thread-0] has deleted [Thread-1-Note580]
```

We can be 100% sure, that creation of an item always takes place before it's deletion in one same thread, so I assume that it is not possible to encounter a situation when a thread wants to delete an item but fails to find one.

**UPDATE**: [Sergey Rybalkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6375041/sergey-rybalkin) has very clearly explained the concept of a programmatic execution order (which I originally did not mention in the question but meant it anyway) and most importantly, he has answered the question:

> If `Thread 1` adds something, `Thread 2` will not see the changes in
>   some situations.

In Java, internally, each object, that we modify actually has a cached copy of it in each thread that works with it. Because the example does not do anything about thread-safety, the array, that we modify, is also cached to each of the thread. Now, that being the case, there is the possibility:

*Note, this is just how I understand it, I am not an expert*

1. `Thread 1` copies the array into its cache.
2. `Thread 2` copies the array into its cache.
3. `Thread 1` adds an item to its cached array.
4. `Thread 2` adds an item to its cached array.
5. `Thread 1` deletes an item from its cached array.
6. `Thread 1` flushes its cached array into the actual array.
7. `JVM` propagates the change and uploads the actual array to all of the users of that object -- to the `Thread 2`. So, the second thread now has the updated version of the array which is currently empty.
8. `Thread 2` deletes an item from its cached array.
9. **Exception**: the list already empty: `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0,`**`Size: -1`**

Comment: p.s. I am aware that you should never `extend Thread`

Comment: do you want synchronization? because both thread access the same resource i.e. notes

Comment: What did you expect after concurrent modification of the same list? Try to read some theory before running the snippet blindly. You need to synchronize your access to this list in order to avoid unpredictable behavior

Comment: Both threads are running asynchronously and you did not have explicit control on it when they are running. So that is why, you are getting different behaviors.

Comment: I understand that synchronization is needed in such a case. But the question is about the understanding of the opposite. This snippet does not actually have any practical sense. I just don't get how can one thread empty the list before the other if they create one item and delete one item each? I feel that to empty the list you would need to delete more than you create, because you create one, you delete one, the other thread does the same, so one should never find the list empty. They can delete each other's note, true, but how can they encounter that it's already empty???

Comment: you mean to say remove(0) can throw IndexOutofBoundException instead of 'Another thread has already deleted the note' as it is empty. am i right??

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal e.g. `Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 1 \n
Thread [Thread-0] has deleted [Thread-1-Note0] \n
 at ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a concurrent modification of a data structure `ArrayList`

1. ArrayList is not Thread safe.
2. Your loop iteration is not atomic.
3. You do not provide any stuff for ordering.

If we name `A1` - add in thread 1, `A2` - add in thread 2, `R1` - remove int thread 1, `R2` - remove in thread 2 and `>` for before.
During one iteration you could get:

1. `A1 > R1 > A2 > R2`
2. `A1 > A2 > R1 > R2`
3. `A1 > A2 > R2 > R1`
4. ...

We only know that always `A1 > R1` and `A2 > R2`
Also a scheduler could perform several iterations in thread 1 and only after switch to thread 2.

So, there is no reason to expect any ordering of operations in your two threads. All that you have in this situation is a programming order of add and remove in a single thread. But you do not have a Happens Before relation. See more in [JLS 17](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html).
But it is better to have a basic understanding first.

Comment: I guess, it has much more to it than I expected. I'll abstract out of it for now and accept the reason as "did not use thread safe methodology". When learn enough I am going to read the JLS and find out exactly why everything happens. But thanks for the answer! spasibo

Comment: When you check carefully what the document you are quoting says ... then those two statements **do** have a happen-before order. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5

Comment: @GhostCat There is no order: `add` in thread A HB `add` in thread B. What are you talking about?

Comment: The order of instructions within thread A, which first adds before deletes?

Comment: @GhostCat It is program order. As a result, yes, you will get HB in a single thread

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin Saw the updated version of your answer. That makes sense. But using this logic when a thread removes it should never run in a situation where there is nothing to delete because `A1 > R1` and `A2 > R2` is always true and we always have something to delete. However, that's not what happens every time. But I'm not really expecting anybody to explain it at this point, as I assumed it has too much to it.

Comment: @SamKruglov No, you are using not thread safe data structure. It means that if thread 1 add something - thread 2 - will not see the changes in some situations. Imagine a simple a simple dynamic array. Sometimes you have to resize it. Imagine that one thread did a resize, but another thread did not get an "updated" array. - Second thread will do the same resize and you will get in trouble. It is just an example

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin wow, you have actually resolved my question. I just found out about `volatile` keyword and, perhaps, that would solve this problem with those separate local copies of the array. But globally, I would , of course, try to find something else specifically designed to be thread-safe rather than make something up myself :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use lists concurrently, you have to chose a thread safe implementation, such as `java.util.Vector`:

```
public static final List<String> notes = new Vector<String>();
```

Alternatively you can use `java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, `Vector` should be considered deprecated, and there are better concurrent collections to use than this (because `Vector`s synchronization is rather primitive and prone to error).